# Multiple expression in the unification algorithm

Tags: prolog, logic, unification

I have solved exercises where I had to unify only expressions of the following form f(..) = f(...). Now I have to solve a similar one but there are 3 expression: f(x, f(x, g(y))), f(u, z) and f(g(y), y). How should I start ? Should I equalize all the expressions at once and then continue with the algorithm ?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I have found that you have to equalize the expressions such that expr1 = expr2, expr2 = expr2,.. expr_n-1 = expr_n and then you can go with the usual algorithm.